# Octave faster method of incrementing with ++ in histogram algo

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, histogram, octave

I am doing a 2D histogram algorithm with bins.
In my code I have the following lines, that I have profiled and they are taking a lot of time.
Is there any way of increasing the performance, by vectorization or any other method?

```
for i = 1 : length(r)
    hist_r(r(i))++;
    hist_g(g(i))++;
    hist_b(b(i))++;
endfor
```

Comment: I removed MATLAB as a tag, since this isn't even valid MATLAB syntax

Comment: arbitrary indexing takes time.

Comment: This is not a 2d histogram. These are 3 individual histograms for each channel. Have you tried the build in function and compared the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used:

```
accumarray(r, 1);
```

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of is

```
MyHist += 1;
```

where `MyHist` is an NBins x 3 array, where the columns represent r, g, and b.